# ForestAdmin: Unlock your data. CORS configuration issue

Tags: node.js, forestadmin

I try to install ForestAdmin but get an error after set up my account and generate my lumber db.

What I did :

```
lumber generate -c 'mongodb+srv://ugo:<my-password>@tlf-qraep.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority' test

cd test

npm install

npm install lumber-forestadmin --save

lumber install lumber-forestadmin --email <my-mail> --projectName test

npm start
```

I got this message so I clicked on it

> Your admin panel is available here: https://app.forestadmin.com/49189

I re-entered my password but I got this error message :

> "Unlock your data
>   Oops, cannot reach your application. Are you sure it is running? If your application is running, you might have a CORS configuration issue."

I checked and my server running on port localhost 3000.

Someone already got this error message?

Thx for the help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally succeed to remove the error. I generated a new lumber on an other port (3003 rather than 3000) and it worked for me !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe another app is using the 3000 port ?